# Firefox not getting launched from Ant and TestNg combination

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ant, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium 2.53.0 and Firefox version is 46.0.1.
Please find the code below which i am running from Ant :

```
 @Test
 public void Browser() {
   // Luanching Firefox browser
   FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("http://flipkart.com");
   driver.quit();
 }
```

**Note:**

If I run the code from eclipse working as expected without any issues. But if I run the same code from Ant using `Build.xml`, I am getting below error:

```
**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within45000 ms**
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: firefox
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: firefox
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ExtensionConnectionFactory.connectTo(ExtensionConnectionFactory.java:46) at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.connectTo(FirefoxDriver.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:109)
at test.NewTest.Browser(NewTest.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.Met
```

Please suggest a solution how to resolve above mentioned issue ?

Comment: any solution to resolve above issue ?

Comment: Something is using port 7054, likely a previous webdriver instance.

Comment: Could you please provide any solution to resolve the above mentioned issue ? .. It really helps me lot... Got struck with this issue.